# How to apply :PluginInstall on Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

I have trouble applying the vim command `:PluginInstall`, When I do it it seems to work, but it opens a `Vundler Installer` (or so I think) window which I can't seem to quit while applying the plugins. I tried with `:q`, `:x` and `:wq` (`:w` don't work on this window apparently), and I also tried restarting my terminal. Also I tried `vim +PluginInstall +qall` from my terminal.

[Here's the window that opens with `:PluginInstall` (on the left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gndwO.jpg)

[And here's when I `:q` the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX4da.jpg) (as you can see, the status bar on the bottom isn't here anymore)

I'm very new to Vim and I guess I did something wrong with the installation or even in my `.vimrc` file (there's still a lot I don't understand in there).

My `.vimrc`:

```
 1 set nocompatible
  2 filetype off
  3 
  4 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
  5 call vundle#begin()
  6 
  7 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
  8 
  9 
 10 Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails'
 11 Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
 12 Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 13 Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
 14 Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
 15 Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
 16 Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
 17 set rtp+=~/.fzf
 18 Plugin 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
 19 call vundle#end()
 20 
 21 
 22 filetype plugin indent on
 23 
 24 set number
 25 set mouse=a
 26 syntax on
 27 set backspace=indent,eol,start
 28 set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
 29 if has("multi_byte")
 30   set encoding=utf-8
 31   setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
 32 else
 33   echoerr "Sorry, this version of (g)vim was not compiled with +multi_byte"
 34 endif
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  If your complaint is that the status line goes away when you close the Vundle window, you probably want to `set laststatus=2` in your .vimrc to force the status line to show even when there is only one window.

Answer (score 1):

`:close` should close the PluginInstall window and return vim to the initial window that was active before running `:PluginInstall`